# What is a good design pattern for the following situation?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have different string distance metric implementations at hand (all of them are in C#) for example, Levensthein, NeedlemanWunsch, Jaccard, etc. The job of these are same basically; take two strings as input and return a similarity score in the range [0,1]. So, I planned to make these classes to implement  the same basic interface, as in the following:

```
public interface IStringDistanceMetric
{
    //Return a similarity between 0 and 1.
    double CompareSimilarity(string strA, string strB);
}
```

Each of my metrics will implement this method. But there are some metrics which will directly operate on two strings, without any other input and there are some metrics which needs some extra parameters( like the penalty given for a gap in one of the input strings, etc.). In general, I can give these parameters either in the constructor stage or just before calculating the similarity score.

My question is, in general, what would be a good design practice in order to handle such differences between the concrete distance classes? I aim that the client code which wants to use any distance metric should be oblivious to any underlying implementation detail, after it has decided use a specific kind of metric. The most obvious way would be to implement something like:

```
  IStringDistanceMetric metric;
  if(metricType == Metric.NeedlemanWunsch)
  {
    metric = new NeedlemanWunsch(parametersNW);
  }
  else if(metricType == Metric.Levensthein)
  {
    metric = new Levensthein(parametersL);
  }
  .
  . 
  .
```

But this doesn't look a good solution to me. I am kind of surprised to find myself stuck at such a basic looking design problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know which you are going to use up-front? Perhaps a factory will fit a little more nicely in here. That way the client just asks for an instance and the factory method contains this `if else` stuff and returns the interface. This makes the assumption the factory can get access to the parameters - it could always take an argument for those. Also allows you to keep your strategy pattern for what implementation of the interface is returned, which is nice.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the way you are trying to do it, you have 2 seperate alghorithms for checking those two strings. Having them in difrent functions and using if's to select which one you should use is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: Agreed with @AdamHouldsworth. Additionally, I would suggest that your client code has the "stringDistanceMetric" _typed_ as interface (not as the actual class type), so you can inject different concrete types.

Comment: Please rephrase your title to clarify what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is highly dependant on how it is used; are the values of these parameters fixed or should they be provided when doing the comparison? If the number of possible values for these parameters is very low, the design used in .NET for [StringComparers](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/stringcomparer.cs) could be followed (courtesy of [sourceof.net](http://sourceof.net/)):

```
private static readonly StringComparer _invariantCulture = new CultureAwareComparer(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, false);        
private static readonly StringComparer _invariantCultureIgnoreCase = new CultureAwareComparer(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, true);      
private static readonly StringComparer _ordinal = new OrdinalComparer(false);
private static readonly StringComparer _ordinalIgnoreCase = new OrdinalComparer(true);        

public static StringComparer InvariantCulture { 
    get {
        return _invariantCulture;
    }
}
```

If you are getting user input or configuration settings to specify your parameter values, and they vary each time you compare strings, a factory method would probably be an appropriate solution, the 'most obvious way' presented in your answer.

Comment: +1 I didn't think of this solution and it is indeed a nice one. This does have the problem that the caller must know implementation details, something I thought OP wanted to avoid. But that is just my two cents.

Comment: I think that there can be the need of changing parameters often. So, in general, I should have a class like : 'StringMetricFactory' which takes all relevant parameters and produces a concrete instance of the metric class I want to use and return it as a reference to the 'IStringDistanceMetric' interface, for example. Is this a suitable solution?

Comment: I think so, or create a method that returns the requested data and 'inject' that in the 'calculator', using `Func<x, y, z> GetMeThisMetrics` for example.

Comment: How does this factory get called? I agree with @PatrickHofman that the implementation details should be preferrably hidden, however the implementation details **must** be known by the caller - otherwise the caller would not have access to the parameters for the appropriate implementation.

Comment: @Bas: Indeed. Or a 'catch-all' as I suggested. It really depends on the amount of knowledge the caller has.

Answer (score 1):

If you want make no difference in the method signatures and want to hide the implementation details, the only option is to treat everything the same, that is, have one signature and parameterize it so one-fits-all.

You can think of supplying the metrics to the method using a class, or using a method containing all the fields. The implementation then decides what parameters are useful and takes those to do the calculations.